# Debug "exc_bad_access" with NSZombie

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I try to debug "exc_bad_access" with NSZombie. Those errors come from sqlite3. 
I already enabled zombie objects in xCode / editScheme/ Diagnostics.
Running the app with Instruments (Zombies) show this message in Console frame:

```
(1330,0x2581000) malloc: *** error for object 0x4c3ea00: non-page-aligned, non-allocated  pointer being freed
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
<End of Run>
```

My question is how to find the object who cause that (here: 0x4c3ea00) ? If you know another way to work with NSZombie, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: if you will click and hold the play(Run) button in xcode you will se the Prifile icon select it and run it a window will appear ad the bottom you will see zombie

Comment: I'm doubtful that NSZombie will help much with errors coming from SQLite.  SQLite does it's own storage management, and you probably violated one of its rules.  (But did you do the breakpoint as instructed?  Knowing where you get the error may be helpful.)

Comment: yes, i put the breakpoint and i know which is the line, but i don't know how to fix that: int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, sql_stmt_getBillingAccount, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL);

Answer (score 0):

YOu can enable NSZombie by editting scheme in Xcode. Also you can add exception breakpoint through Xcode. Refer image to locate from where to add exception breakpoint.[image]

Comment: Thanks, but was not my question. I already enable NSZombie. How to find out the object who generate the error using the message displayed in Instruments/Zombies/Console ?

Comment: I got the idea that you are using zombies through instruments. I am asking to use by editing scheme. Plus use exception breakpoint that will tell you where your code is crashing and then you can introspect on your own which object is deallocated. Else no option

Comment: Thank you, i added Exception Breakpoint. The idea is the code crash very rarely and i was thinking is much easly to use NSZombie to find out which is the object. But i don't know how to interprate the message show by Instruments in Console.

Answer (score 0):

The message tells you.

Go to breakpoints and add a symbolic breakpoint on `malloc_error_break`.

When the breakpoint fires the code causing the error will be in the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks, i did that and now the code stops to: int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, sql_stmt_getBillingAccount, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL); Thread4:Exc_bad_access(code=1, address=0x14). How i find out which one is the object?

Comment: @Developer3000 Couldn't tell you without seeing more code, however I would suspect a previous `sqlStatement` hasn't been freed using `sqlite3_finalize()`.

Comment: Thanks, i just check that and is fine. However, should i use "int" or NSInteger to store the response ?

Comment: @Developer3000 That doesn't matter.